# How do I find if my version of ActiveState Tk/Tcl supports TkTreectrl and the correct module name?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I would like to use the TkTreeCtrl for a GUI I'm building. I have installed ActivePython 3.3.4.1 and ActiveState Tkinter 8.5, which passes its self-test. I tried the multilistbox.py demo from http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net and it crashes because it can't find treectrl. from TkTreectrl import * produces no error message. Can anyone tell me how I determine the bindings in tkinter? How do I determine if treectrl exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from tkinter import ttk
>>> ttk.Treeview
<class 'tkinter.ttk.Treeview'>
```

I use the Docs Server (on the Python start menu) tkinter page, the Python tkinter docs (occasionally) and the [New Mexico Text](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) tkinter docs

Comment: The New Mexico site is very useful, thanks. I believe TreeView is part of the native Tk/Tcl, but I'm looking for an extension, TkTreeCtrl. This is more of a python question, but is there a way to list all the bindings added by an import?

Comment: you mean like `import xxx; dir(xxx)`?

Comment: exactly like dir(xxx). Thanks!